# Does Composed looks affect Display Template, Layout Pages, Design Package

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, composed-looks

I am having a requirement to apply themes using "Composed Looks" which i have created successfully.But my question is do after applying theme via Composed Looks will it affect Display template,Layout pages , Design Package or any other issue can it cause.

Any help is appreciated.